# In Fish, how do I cd to the closest parent with a .git directory?

Tags: fish

I use Fish shell. Sometimes, I find myself in a child directory of a child directory of a child directory, several layers deep, and I want to return to the closest parent with a `.git` directory, as this directory represents the root project directory, so to speak.

For example, let's say I have this layout:

```
./
└── countries/
    ├── .git/
    └── regions/
        └── cities/
```

Whethere I am in `countries/` or `countries/regions/` or `countries/regions/cities/`, I would like this command to change directory to `countries/`, because it is the directory that contains `.git`.

How do I do this in Fish?

Answer (score 4):

`git rev-parse` has a "--show-cdup" option that'll print an argument to give to cd:

```
set -l cd (git rev-parse --show-cdup 2>/dev/null); and cd $cd
```

The `2>/dev/null` silences the "not a git repository" error, and `git rev-parse --show-cdup` will return falsey in that case, so this won't do any `cd` if used outside of a git repo.

Alternatively you could use `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`. I'm reasonably sure that `--show-cdup` will go by the *physical* working directory, so if you had ended up in a git repo by going through a symlink it might print the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that accomplishes this:

```
function cdroot
  set directory_x (pwd)

  while test -n "$directory_x" -a ! -e "$directory_x/.git"
    set parts (string split '/' $directory_x)
    set --erase parts[(count $parts)]
    set directory_x (string join '/' $parts)
  end

  if test -n "$directory_x"
    cd "$directory_x"
  else
    echo "Could not find closest root directory with .git child" >&2
    return 1
  end

end
```

To install it, put it in `~/.config/fish/functions/cdroot.fish`

Comment: Note that you can use `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to get the absolute path of the current repository. This may simplify your function a bit.

Answer (score 1):

While `git rev-parse` can make this trivial, here's a naïve, generalised solution that could be adapted to a non-`.git` use case.

```
set start "$PWD"
while test ! -e .git
  if ! cd .. ; or test "$PWD" = /
    break
  end
end
if test ! -e .git
  cd "$start"
end
```

Comment: The trouble with this approach is that it breaks returning to the previous current working directory using `cd -` . It will also cd to `/` if it can't find the `.git` directory.

Comment: Good point about ending up in `/`, easily rectified. Your question doesn't mention anything about preserving `cd -` so that wasn't in consideration.